# Replace digits in a number with other random digits

Tags: php, string, random, replace

**Problem:**

- I'm trying to write a function which replace four digits in a number
- Number syntax is XX.XXXXXXX (but length may vary but min. 8 digits)
- Digits I want to change always 5th, 6th, 7th and 8th (marked as Z --> XX.XXZZZZXXXX)
- The number to replace Z, must be random (or 4 random digits in each Z)

**Example:**

`x=12.3456789 --> function --> 12.34xxxx9`

Where xxxx is a random number with 4 digits or four different digits.

**Documentation:**

- [To replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)
- [To generate a random number](http://php.net/manual/es/function.random-int.php)

**What I've tried:**

Note: I'm starting with coding... super rookie here.

```
function mynumber($x) {
//ok, it's not elegant but here i'm trying to get a number of 4 digits instead of digit by digit
$replacement = var_dump(random_int(1111, 9999));
//I've read about string replace but as the lenght may vary, i don't know how to delimitate the digits i want to change
$x = str_replace($x, $replacement, -?);
}
```

Comment: how about `$num = substr_replace($num, random_int(1000, 9999), 5, 4);`?

Comment: If you always want to replace the 5th, 6th, 7th and 8th digit, there's no need to worry about the length. You could read and learn about turning a number into a string, which will makes it much easier to replace the digits you want, instead of trying to do some math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substr_replace()` as `str_replace()` will replace other matching digits not just in the 5th through 8th place:

```
$x = substr_replace($x, $replacement, 5, 4);
```

Also, you need to `return $x;` in the function.  Or to modify the passed variable, you need to pass it by reference:

```
function mynumber(&$x) {
```

Comment: Thank you. So, correct and **good** syntax could be something like:

`function mynumber($x) {
$replacement = var_dump(random_int(1000, 9999));
$x = substr_replace($x, $replacement, 5, 4);
return $x;
}`